# Pig - MAX is not working after grouping

Tags: hadoop, group-by, apache-pig

I am working with `Pig 0.12.1` and `Map-R`. I am trying to find **max** of a field after grouping the relation on some other field. Refer the following pig script and structure of relation in comments-

```
r1 = foreach SomeRelation generate flatten(group) as (c1 , c2);
-- r1: {c1: biginteger,c2: biginteger}
r2 = group r1 by c1;
-- r2: {group: chararray,r1: {(c1: chararray,c2: biginteger)}}

DUMP r2;
/* output -
1234|{(1234,9876)}
2345|{(2345,8765)}
3456|{(3456,7654)}
4567|{(4567,6543)}
*/

r3 = foreach r2 generate group as c1, MAX(r1.c2) as c2;
```

I am getting the following error

```
Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.MAX as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

Script Explained-

> I am flattening group of SomeRelation into c1, c2 and then regrouping
>   on c1 to generate max of c2 with each c1 group.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like the problem is that Pig doesn't allow **MAX**(or for that matter aggregate functions like **SUM** etc) on biginteger. Had to use long as a datatype for this to work. Refer the following-

```
r1 = foreach SomeRelation generate flatten(group) as (c1 , c2:long);
-- r1: {c1: biginteger,c2: long}
```

Strangely, there's no documentation highlighting this almost like datatypes biginteger and bigdecimal.

Comment: You're right, in org.apache.pig.builtin.MAX source code, in the getArgToFuncMapping, BigInteger is not present.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can use the group keyword under the flatten. Also, have you considered tokenizing the group before flattening it. See this for example:

```
       load_data = LOAD '/PIG_TESTS_ALL/WordCount' as (line); 
       tokenizing_data = FOREACH load_data generate flatten(TOKENIZE(line)) as word; 
       group_data = GROUP tokenizing_data by word; 
       Result = FOREACH group_data generate group,COUNT(tokenizing_data); 
       dump Result;
```

This is actually for word count, You can probably build on this to find max value based on what you want to do.

Comment: 1. flatten works on a group.
2. I dont need to tokenize group as its a tuple of two bigintegers

Answer (score 0):

We now know the problem was the unability of MAX to handle biginteger.

You should be able to group and get the max like this, and compare results with combination of order + limit :

```
r1 = FOREACH SomeRelation GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (c1, c2);
r3 = FOREACH (group r1 by c1) {
    -- you may want to apply a function on a single column
    -- or compare sort + limit to MAX
    list = ORDER $1 BY c2 DESC;
    list_max = LIMIT list 1;
    GENERATE group AS c1, MAX(r1.c2) AS c2, list_max;
}
```

Comment: This is just a shorthand version of what I wrote in the problem statement.

Comment: yes, but it allow to make other tests, such as selecting only one colon like `onlyc2 = $1.c2;` and then to make the MAX on that.

Comment: Yes it does and if it's meant as a suggestion then you can either edit the problem statement to highlight this or add it as a comment. Thanks anyway!